# Json 1.0.1 is not installing

Tags: xamarin

I'm working on a xamarine (android) mobile app. It requires JSON libraries but the package named as `json.(version : 1.0.1)` is not installing through NUGet visual studio 2017. When I click install nothing happens.

Comment: what does the package manager console display?

Comment: It shows nothing ..... when i aceept terms and conditions on dialog box  dialog box disappear and nothing happen more ,,,,, while other packages show progress during installation.